# GitLab authentication issue on ApacheDS 2.0

Tags: gitlab, apacheds

I`m currenty trying to hook up Gitlab on a LDAP system, ApacheDS. Both systems are set up and are running by itself.

But when I try to use LDAP login I get the following error:

```
Could not authorize you from Ldap because "Invalid response-type in search: 24".
```

I'm struggeling now, since I couldn't find any useful informations on this error message.

I ran a `tcpdump` while trying to logon:

```
08:57:15.914072 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [S], seq 2669576257, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 776877391 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0  
08:57:15.914102 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [S.], seq 3306189689, ack 2669576258, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 584211093 ecr 
776877391,nop,wscale 6], length 0   
08:57:15.914436 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877391 ecr 584211093], length 0    
08:57:15.914453 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [P.], seq 1:37, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877391 ecr 584211093], length 36    
08:57:15.914459 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [.], ack 37, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211093 ecr 776877391], length 0  
08:57:15.949694 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [P.], seq 1:90, ack 37, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211129 ecr 776877391], length 89   
08:57:15.949955 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [.], ack 90, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877427 ecr 584211129], length 0  
08:57:15.950363 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [P.], seq 37:212, ack 90, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877427 ecr 584211129], length 175  
08:57:15.989682 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [.], ack 212, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211169 ecr 776877427], length 0   
08:57:16.024090 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [P.], seq 90:171, ack 212, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211203 ecr 776877427], length 81  
08:57:16.024182 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [F.], seq 171, ack 212, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211203 ecr 776877427], length 0
08:57:16.025632 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [F.], seq 212, ack 172, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877502 ecr 584211203], length 0
08:57:16.025645 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [.], ack 213, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211204 ecr 776877502], length 0
08:57:15.914072 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [S], seq 2669576257, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 776877391 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:57:15.914102 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [S.], seq 3306189689, ack 2669576258, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 584211093 ecr 
776877391,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:57:15.914436 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877391 ecr 584211093], length 0
08:57:15.914453 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [P.], seq 1:37, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877391 ecr 584211093], length 36
08:57:15.914459 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [.], ack 37, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211093 ecr 776877391], length 0
08:57:15.949694 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [P.], seq 1:90, ack 37, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211129 ecr 776877391], length 89 
08:57:15.949955 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [.], ack 90, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877427 ecr 584211129], length 0   
08:57:15.950363 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [P.], seq 37:212, ack 90, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877427 ecr 584211129], length 17    
08:57:15.989682 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [.], ack 212, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211169 ecr 776877427], length 0   
08:57:16.024090 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [P.], seq 90:171, ack 212, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211203 ecr 776877427], length 81   
08:57:16.024182 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [F.], seq 171, ack 212, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211203 ecr 776877427], length 0    
08:57:16.025632 IP 192.168.85.18.41489 > 192.168.85.19.ldap: Flags [F.], seq 212, ack 172, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 776877502 ecr 584211203], length 0
08:57:16.025645 IP 192.168.85.19.ldap > 192.168.85.18.41489: Flags [.], ack 213, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 584211204 ecr 776877502], length 0
```

Since I'm not that deep into this materia I'd really glad for any hints and help.

Comment: Which GitLab and ApacheDS versions are you using? Is it a library issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333903/6309?